# Can my institution see what papers I'm accessing?

Tags: publications

The other day I was reading a paper on IEEE. To access the paper I needed to sign in through my institution. On the bottom of the paper, it read:

> Accessed through [my institution name] at Oct 24, 9:30 PM

Will my institution be able to see all the papers I'm reading?

Comment: Your institution can see all the papers you are reading.  They can also see all the papers you are not reading, as long as they are open access or in journals they subscribe to.  I think your question is a different one... :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure just why you are concerned that somebody is looking at the technical papers you read. Are some NSFW somehow? In general, librarians are very concerned about privacy of their patrons, and would fight tooth and nail should they ever find out their institution is tracking individuals reading habits. They do need high level summary statistics for business purposes.

Comment: I'd also note that if you were to go into the library and check out a book, they'd obviously have records. If you were to inter-library loan request a article, a human would handle it. Libraries also do analytics by recording items that are pulled but not checked out, and then reshelved, one reason why they tell you not to reshelve items.

Comment: haha no its nothing different. i just was reading a paper about crimes and i don't want my college to think I'm trying to become a criminal

Comment: @JonCuster I disagree with the thrust of your comment, which seems to be "privacy is very important, but why do you want privacy anyway?"

Comment: @usul - I disagree that was the thrust of my comment. The major point is that the librarians are very protective of privacy. As for the other bit, I've never worried about my various institutions eavesdropping on my technical reading...

Answer (score 34):

Your library will get aggregate data from the publishers along the lines of "in this month, 473 user sessions read 621 papers on the service". (The standard for this is [COUNTER](https://www.projectcounter.org/), and I assume IEEE use it). They won't be told "at 5.11 am on Sunday 20th, Steve downloaded..."

However, that data does exist, somewhere. If you are going through your university network there are situations in which it could in theory be identified from their logs, in much the same way that they could tell you then read a news story and finished for the day. The same is true for your home internet connection, but the widespread use of secure HTTPS connections make this level of detailed visibility less common than it used to be.

If you are signing in through Shibboleth authentication or similar, the university will know that you were authenticated for that provider at a particular time, but may not exactly know what items you read. (I would have to dig into the mechanism to be confident either way here). The publisher will also have a log of what you read, and that you were an authenticated user from X, but probably not precisely who you are.

It is vanishingly unlikely (and probably, in many jurisdictions, illegal) for this information to be used other than for things like troubleshooting and tracing abuse, however. So no-one is going to get sent a file of 'here's everything the department read this week, we highlighted Steve'.

But *if* there are problems, someone might well get an email that says 'user STEVE logged in from a weird looking Moldovan IP and downloaded 5000 papers in ten minutes last night, so the system then shut the account out, you should probably look into this before we reenable it'.

Comment: *If you are going through your university network it could in theory be identified from the logs* -- actually no, because almost every website uses SSL today. So the IEEE's server knows which article I downloaded, and they can tell anyone they want, but everyone else that just observes your internet connection can only tell that you downloaded *something* from the IEEE's server.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni ah, I may be showing my age here in terms of what visibility I expect :) although presumably if it was on university hardware as well as the network there is the potential for them to log browser histories if they wish? Will rephrase.

Comment: Just to be clear, the bottom line is that if I want to read a paper about how to dissolve human bones into acid, I should not do it through my institution, correct? Asking for a friend.

Comment: @Stef No, because your institution would not know which paper you read. And the publisher does not know that you are not a forensic to check out which chemicals would help dissolving human bones.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni If the network requires you to install their certificate (as Eduroam does here for example) they have more options, though a well-set-up server should still cause the client to give an error if the network tries to MITM your connection

Comment: @ChrisH Are you sure your Eduroam installs a SSL MITM certificate and not just one to authenticate the Radius auth server? This seems much more common to me. Do you insert the certificate in your browser or in the Wifi configuration window?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni on Windows and Android, it's installed by an app which you can't avoid.  So where it installs and what for is a mystery to the user.  From the behaviour on Linux I'm pretty certain that our setup does just use it to authenticate the connection, but once you've accepted certificate installation as part of the connection process, the trust position has changed - and most users won't even realise.

Comment: The one situation I can think of where the school may care enough to look is if the publisher claims a large violation of the terms of the institutional subscription -- like if someone opened a service that gives no subscribers pdfs of papers they're not entitled to -- and they get a cease and desist.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using your institution's network, yes, they could see all of your internet activity, including your accesses to the digital library of IEEE. But it is rather unlikely they would bother.

If your university wanted, they can use a man-in-the-middle attacks when establishing an SSL connection by using their own certificates. Some corporations with high security needs do this. They would need to get you to install a root certificate for this. Otherwise, they can tell the sites to which you go.

If you access the library via a token provided by the university via the log in through your institution, they can keep track of the token and its destination.

However, at least in the US, librarians will fight tooth and nails to dissuade the institution from getting this information while accessing library functions.

Comment: not my institutions network. im doing it from my home. but I'm using my institution login (ex: myname@institution.edu) to read IEEE papers since it often asks you to "sign in through institution"

Comment: In this age I would assume the website uses SSL, so the network provider can see OP is accessing IEEE's library, but not which page or article they are downloading.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I don't know enough about IEEE and SSL to know whether this is relevant, but I know that many article databases don't serve the paper directly, but return a DOI link to it on an outside server. For example, if I use MathSciNet to look up the proof of Fermat's last theorem, the database listing is at https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1333036 but actually reading the article sends me to https://doi.org/10.2307/2118560 which redirects to https://www.jstor.org/stable/2118560?origin=crossref . It seems to me that this could leak more information.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer With SSL the full destination URL is not leaked, only the server name.

Comment: Downvoting as this is probably not accurate

Comment: "But it is rather unlikely they would bother" that could vary *a lot* depending on country.

Answer (score 4):

The counting statistics not only applies to publications (as in *primary* literature), but equally to databases your school then may highlight e.g., as *top* in a given specialty (example [University of Vienna](https://usearch.univie.ac.at/primo-explore/dbsearch?query=contains,dbcategory,&tab=jsearch_slot&sortby=title&vid=UWI&lang=en_US&offset=0&databases=category,Chemie)), *most useful* (example [University of Geneva](https://www.unige.ch/biblio/en/disciplines/chemistry-and-biochemistry/articles-journals-databases/)), or *recommended* (example [Polytechnique Montréal](https://libguides.biblio.polymtl.ca/az.php?s=93507)).  And if the electronic catalogue does not display these on the library's web site, beside the subscription fee, the number of accesses per license period and database still are arguments to (dis)continue the provision of access to all on campus' network, or only to the few interested groups of a department (perhaps especially if groups/schools do not team up).

Comment: Good to see a Matter Modeler here!

Comment: @user1271772 Oh ... Since the first time I recall one of your faculty delivered an inspiring lecture at our school with *food for thought* well beyond the talk he was invited to deliver   (either Donald Knuth, or Robert Grubbs), the classy, iconic torch on their back pack is among my first associations with «Caltech» leading to a friendly tip to hat to appreciate your work, and curiosity about «what are your news».  You can't «unsee it» once your eye spots them e.g., in the airport.

Answer (score -3):

**Yes they can**.

Your institutional library uses data on what papers you're reading to decide which journals to subscribe to.

Comment: This answer would benefit from some more explanation. Who gives the library these data? IEEE? With how much detail? Are they given in anonymized/aggregated form, or can OP be identified?

Comment: I recommend that you delete this and make it a comment. It's been flagged for "length and quality" and in this case probably more for "length".